# Dynamic memory allocation for socket C

Tags: c, sockets, memory-management, malloc, realloc

I want to reserve dynamic memory from a socket. The size of the response is variable so I want to use realloc to allocate the proper memory size.

This is the code snippet that takes care of it:

```
char *ptr = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char),1024);
char *ptr2 = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char),1024);
//printf("aaaaaaa  %p bbbbbbbb",ptr);
int nDataLength;
int i = 0;
while ((nDataLength = recv(Socket, ptr, 1024, 0)) > 0){

    if (i > 0){//prepare in case that the response is bigger than 1024 bytes
        printf("Data len: %d\n", nDataLength);
        printf("%p points toa %d len: %d\n", ptr, *ptr, ((1024 * i) + nDataLength));
        ptr2 = (char*)realloc(ptr2,((1024*i)+nDataLength));
        printf("%p pints toa %d\n", ptr2, *ptr2);
        system("pause");
        memcpy(ptr2, ptr, nDataLength);
    }
    memcpy(ptr2, ptr, nDataLength);
    i++;
}
```

The problem is that the buffer that I receive from the socket is allways being memcpyed to the same address so I am overwriting the previous buffer. How can I move ptr2 to not overwrite the previous store buffer? It must be somethin like:

`memcpy(ptr2+((1024 * i), ptr, nDataLength);` but it does not work.

Thank you

Comment: I feel it should work, with out any issues. Could you post the entire code.

Answer (score 2):

First:

1. [Please don't cast the return value of `calloc()` in C. Or `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).
2. Don't use `sizeof (char)` to "scale" allocations, it's always just 1 so it's pointless.
3. There's no need to use `calloc()` if you're going to `recv()` into the memory anyway.

Your problem is that you keep passing `recv()` the *start* of your growing buffer, instead of the *next free location to store at*. You should have something like `put + nTotalLength` as the target for `recv()`, and then do `nTotalLength += nDataLength` after each successful reception.

Comment: 1- If I remove the (char*) before calloc I get this error: `cannot convert from 'void *' to 'char *'`                                     2- I use it to do it compiler independant because char en c has not the same length than in c++                                                  3- I guess that I need to reserve some memory for the buffer that I am going to receive right?                                                     4- It can be done in the way that you say or in my way. It's the same. The problem is that I dont know how to sum a value (1024) to a pointer. How can I do it? Thanks!!!

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted to program in C and C++ at the same time. I wouldn't have answered if I had. :) (Your tagging says "C").

Comment: No problem. But, how can I sum an address to a value? So the address returned by calloc and a value like 1024? Thanks

Comment: `put + nTotalLength` adds an offset (an integer value) to a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

&ptr[1024] gives the address after ptr ends. You just have 2 buckets. you need to consume before you add more data to it. If its a TCP socket based protocol (or any stream based), you need to just read the header, the header should have a indication of data size. malloc for that size, consume the data and then go read the next header.

Comment: Actually reading the header is much better because I can just reserve memory one time and for the full packet. How can I read the size header? Thank you

Comment: I just realized that the header give you the size of the fragmented message not the size of the full packet. So in that case this is useless